# Django 1.9 how to query model using prefetch_related() and get the results which prefetched data existing

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I'm making a query to retrieve a model using prefetch_related.

```
products = products.prefetch_related('payments').all()
```

However, I got all the products but some of them have no payments.

Is there a way to retrieve products which have payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter like

`products = Product.objects.filter(payments__isnull=False).prefetch_related('payments')`